# How does one apply a Javascript function to all Tumblr posts and not just the most recent one?

Tags: javascript, tumblr

I've been working on a Tumblr theme, and one problem is that most of the posts are photos. Each type of post has a defined wrapper color and photo posts are pink, but I wanted to make photo posts more diverse than that, so I implemented some Javascript that would take the length of the caption on the photo post and use that to define what color the wrapper would be. I based it on caption length because I was hoping it would act on each post differently and separately, because there was a problem with that in a previous function I wrote using "Math.random". But now it only acts on the most recent post. How do you suppose you could change the code so that the function would apply to every photo post on the page?

Here's the html referenced:

```
{block:Photo}
  <li class="post photo">
    <div class="content">
      <div name="photowrap" id="photowrap" 
       style="width: 330px;
       background-color: #F6CEE3;
       padding: 1.2em 15px;
       margin: 0 auto;
       border: 3px white solid;
       border-radius: 20px;">
        <center><img src="{PhotoUrl-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/></center>

          {block:Caption}
            <h4><div class="caption" id="phocap">{Caption}</div></h4>
          {/block:Caption}

            <center><div class="notes"><a href="{ReblogURL}" title="Reblog"><img src="http://www.zomm.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/recycle-2.jpg"></a><a href="{Permalink}"><img src="http://exchangedownloads.smarttech.com/public/content/0d/0d14fcdc-8db0-4272-b1d0-be30b37bd147/previews/medium/0001.png">{PostNotes}</a></div></center>


      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
{/block:Photo}
```

And here's the Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var wrapCol = document.getElementById("photowrap");
        var captionnum = document.getElementById("phocap").innerHTML.length;
        if (captionnum == 0)
          wrapCol.style.backgroundColor="#F6CEE3";
        if (captionnum > 0 && captionnum < 50)
          wrapCol.style.backgroundColor="#A7EAFF";
        if (captionnum >= 50)
          wrapCol.style.backgroundColor="#CEF6A3";

</script>
```

Comment: How can that code operate on multiple posts? You're just looking up IDs, and IDs must be unique. There's no loop in your code to process multiple elements.

Comment: Can you show the HTML with the templates expanded?

Comment: I had assumed the Post blocks had a loop integrated into them that allowed it to apply one set of code instead of writing a new block of code for each entry, but maybe it still does need a loop. Also, where would you like me to expand it to?

Comment: It will do a loop. But the Javascript in each iteration of the loop is processing the same elements, not the elements from that iteration, because you're accessing them by ID. IDs are expected to be unique in the entire document, they're not relative to the current iteration of the loop.

Comment: And it doesn't look like your Javascript is inside the block, so it won't be in the loop.

Comment: I placed the Javascript inside the block, trying it inside every <div> and <li> in that block, as well as replacing "getElementsById" with "getElementsByName", but now there's no result. If I keep "getElementsById" it returns a result but it's still only affecting the most recent post.

Comment: You can't just replace `getElementById` with `getElementsByName`. The former returns a single element, the latter returns a NodeList, which is like an array. You have to write an explicit loop to process the list -- the loop created by the `block` won't do it.

Comment: Yes, using getElementsByName and making a loop to go through all the photo posts through the page, while also putting it outside of the Photo block, got it to work! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may do it.

```
var wrapCols = document.getElementsByName('photowrap');
for (var i = 0; i < wrapCols.length; i++) {
    var wrapCol = wrapCols[i];
    var captionnum = wrapCol.getElementsByClassName("caption")[0].innerHTML.length;
    if (captionnum == 0) {
      wrapCol.style.backgroundColor="#F6CEE3";
    } else if (captionnum < 50) {
      wrapCol.style.backgroundColor="#A7EAFF";
    } else {
      wrapCol.style.backgroundColor="#CEF6A3";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `id` attribute by definition is intended to be unique, going by the fact that your code uses `document` I can only assume that the block is added to the page before you style it.
You need to replace the calls to `document.getElementById` by one that is able to select multiple nodes at once and return a nodeList for you to loop over.

If you dont care about supporting older browsers, then `querySelectorAll` in combination with the class names should work for this.
If you do wish to support older browsers you may need to reply on `getElementsByName` and then traversing the DOM to get at the nodes you wish to edit.

If this is all to much work for you, I recommend you start using a javascript library such as jQuery, as these libraries make it a lot easier to manipulate the DOM.